# Google Javascript Data API for Calendar - Event times not available

Tags: javascript, gdata

I would like to use the gdata API to retrieve some event entries from a public calendar feed. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
var calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

var feedUri = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/.../public/basic';
var gquery = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventQuery(feedUri);

gquery.setFutureEvents(true);
gquery.setMaxResults(10);

var callback = function(result) {       
    var entries = result.feed.entry;    
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ ) {
      var entry = entries[i];
      var title = entry.getTitle().getText();
      var times = entry.getTimes();
      alert("Title: " + title + " | Times: " + times);
    }    
}
calendarService.getEventsFeed(gquery, callback);
```

(Feed URI is the public (or private) XML-Feed for a Google Apps Calendar)

I expected to find the event times in *times* but it is an empty array. Which is in some way logical, because the actual feed in *feedUri* doesn't contain any time information.

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong? How to retreive calendar entries which include event times?
- Why is there a method getTimes() if it's completely useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I've just seen you're using the "basic" feed - have you tried the "full" feed instead? The description of the basic feed is:

> Basic Atom feed without any extension
>   elements. Its  and
>    properties contain
>   pre-rendered HTML.

Additionally, you need to be aware of single events vs recurrent events. Information about recurrent events is available via `getRecurrence()`. For individual events, `getTimes()` will give the right information.

If you don't see the information via the API, try looking at the source data directly and see whether you can see it there.